# Jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js + cordova error

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am trying to include jquery to my cordova project. But when compiling I get this error. I don't really know what that means.

EROOR : http://prntscr.com/bk4dn3

HTML INCLUDES : http://prntscr.com/bk4fnn

And the code that is using jquery:

```
    $.stringBuilder = function () {
    this.buffer = [];
    };

    $.stringBuilder.prototype = {

    cat: function (what) {
        this.buffer.push(what);
        return this;
    },

    string: function () {
        return this.buffer.join('');
    },
    reset: function(){
        this.buffer = [];
    }
    };
    var questions = ["Si tout va bien je compte prendre ma retraite dans ...",
    "Comment pourrais-je qualifier ma situation financière actuelle ?",
    "Notre revenu familial annuel actuel (rentes comprises) avant impôt se situe…",
    "Je voudrais pouvoir suivre l’évolution des rendements sur mes placements...",
    "Je sais qu’il est recommandé d’avoir de l’argent en réserve pour faire face aux imprévus (exemple : une perte ou une diminution de revenu). De combien de mois de revenu familial net disposons-nous actuellement ?"
    ];
    var html = new $.stringBuilder();
    for (var i in questions)
    html.cat("<tr><td>").cat("<b>" + (i++) + ". </b>").cat("</td>       <td>").cat(i).cat("</td></tr>");
    while ($('#questionnaire').firstChild) {
    $('#questionnaire').removeChild($('#questionnaire').firstChild);
    }
    $('#questionnaire').append(html.string());
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332)

Comment: I am sorry it's my first time to post on this forum. @AndrewMyers

Comment: @MoussaTraore It more of your code issue i feel. Try commenting the cat function code and try once to isolate the issue

Comment: Hi I have been able to bypass this by using another version of JQuery. Still dont understand how it worked. The problem I am having now is to parse html_string into DOM elements. Do u have any idea on how i could do that please ? @Gandhi

Comment: @Moussa could you brief more on the requirement